# I can compile it but i can't run this java program

Tags: java, compilation

> Hello guys
>
> I was write a java program and i can compile it but when i want to run
>   this program, an error will be displayed that say: "Could not find or
>   load main class undefined".
>
> what is the problem??

```
package testmatrixmethods;
class TestMatrixMethods {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] a=readMatrix();
        writeMatrix(a);
        System.out.println("Max in Matrix --> "+maxMatrix(a,a.length,a[0].length));

    }
    public static int maxMatrix(int[][] m){
        int max = m[0][0];
        for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<m[i].length;j++)
                if(max<m[i][j])
                    max=m[i][j];
        return max;
    }
    public static int maxMatrix(int[][] m,int rows,int cols){
        int max = m[0][0];
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
                if(max<m[i][j])
                    max=m[i][j];
        return max;
    }
    public static int[][] readMatrix(){
        java.util.Scanner input=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        int rows,cols;
        int[][] m;
        System.out.println("enter nuumber of rows: ");
        rows=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter number of columns: ");
        cols=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter "+rows+"x"+cols+" interger numbers");
        m=new int[rows][cols];
        for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<m[0].length;j++)
                m[i][j]=input.nextInt();
        return m;
    }
    public static void writeMatrix(int[][] m){
        for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++){
                    System.out.print("|");
            for(int j=0;j<m[i].length;j++)
                System.out.printf("%6d" , m[i][j]);
                        System.out.println("|");
                System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the command line you are using to execute the class?

Comment: How are you invoking your program?

Comment: You can't run your program, I cant guess where did you run your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you in folder `test`

1. create file `TestMatrixMethods.java` with your code.
2. create folder `compiled`
3. compile your java class `javac -d compiled TestMatrixMethods.java`
4. in folder `compiled` emerged folder with same name as your java class
   package name and this folder contains TestMatrixMethods.class
5. in folder `test` put this command

   ```
   java -cp "compiled" testmatrixmethods.TestMatrixMethods
   ```
6. done

Comment: thanks for your help, it's worked. but what is the problem?? Still i can't compile it like any other program in regular way.  am i doing something wrong??

Comment: @AliBahadorani what is wrong depends of way you tried to execute a program. Since you not provide a command you putted to console i simple give you a right way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

you need to run a **java** virtual machine and pass it your classes/jars. You would also have to pass it the name of the main class which contains your 'main' function which will be **testmatrixmethods.TestMatrixMethods** int your case.

i.e. for windows:

```
%JAVA% -cp myProject.jar;relatedProject.jar mtestmatrixmethods.TestMatrixMethods -myProgramArs
```